# Disabling QComboBox in pyqt

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox

Is it possible to disable `QComboBox` in pyqt like we can do it in Win Forms(C#) since I could not find any option in the `QComboBox` manual. I want to enable `QcomboBox` only when admin logins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer to my question,

```
QComboBox.setEnabled(False) # disable comboBox
```

and

```
QComboBox.setEnabled(True) # enable comboBox
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do :

```
QComboBox.setDisabled(True)
QComboBox.setDisabled(False)
```